# Получение потока по URL android java

Tags: java, android

Не могу открыть поток для чтения по URL.
В манифесте разрешение на интернет добавил.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);
        String s = null;
        s = connectToSoccer();       
        tv.setText(s);
    }

    private String connectToSoccer() throws IOException {
            String s = null;

            URL url = new URL("http://www.soccer.ru");
            URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
            con.setConnectTimeout(1000);
            InputStream in = con.getInputStream();
            s = StreamReader(in);
        return s;
        }
```

Приложение вылетает на строчке `InputStream in = con.InputStream();`
Пробовал также через `HttpURLConnection` - вылет при попытке получить `input stream`

Comment: Когда вы выкладываете код и говорите, что он "падает" то надо помимо строки, на коей он падает приложить имя выпадающей ошибки и/или её вывод в логах

Answer (score 2):

У вас `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. С API>=14 нельзя делать запрос в сеть из основного потока приложения. Вам надо вынести работу с сетью в другой поток. Для начала попробуйте сделать это через `AsyncTask`